# Osmdroid and Google Satellite demo

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, osmdroid

After searching quite a bit,

What is the easiest way to show Google Satellite info via Osmdroid?

I see GoogleWrapper
Bing? 
MapQuestArial?

Can you show good examples?

Comment: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to show nice Satellite maps in osmdroid?

With MapQuestAerial, min zoom level is 11 => you cannot zoom-in close enough, it's useless.

I would recommend MapBox Satellite. It rules! 
[image: Roma - St Peter place]http://osmbonuspack.googlecode.com/svn/BonusPackDownloads/img/osmbonuspackdemo_10_1.png

Usage:

```
MapBoxTileSource.retrieveMapBoxMapId(this);
OnlineTileSourceBase MAPBOXSATELLITELABELLED = new MapBoxTileSource("MapBoxSatelliteLabelled", ResourceProxy.string.mapquest_aerial, 1, 19, 256, ".png");
TileSourceFactory.addTileSource(MAPBOXSATELLITELABELLED);
map.setTileSource(MAPBOXSATELLITELABELLED);
```

and in your Manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="MAPBOX_MAPID" android:value="...YOUR MAPBOX MAP ID..." />
```

I never tried Bing Satellite.